# Unit test of Bokeh plot

Tags: python, unit-testing, bokeh

I am a beginner at unit tests, and at Bokeh. How do I test if a Bokeh plot actually exist and belongs to the proper class?

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
p = figure(...)
..
assert isinstance(p, type(figure)), 'it is not a bokeh plot'
```

returns 'it is not a bokeh plot'...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would it be easier to look at the string of the class rather than creating the object and comparing instances?

```
import unittest
from bokeh.plotting import figure

class BokehScriptTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_plot(self):
        p = figure()
        self.assertEqual(str(type(p)),"<class 'bokeh.plotting.figure.Figure'>")
```

So we have the object p, access it's type, and get the string.  It also makes it easier to see what you expect to get out.

Comment: Thanks! Not exactly what I was looking for, but it's a beautiful workaround!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your test is that `figure` is a function. So doing `type(figure)` returns `function`. Whereas calling `figure()` returns an instance of the `Figure` class.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.plotting.figure import Figure
p = figure(...)
..
assert isinstance(p, Figure), 'it is not a bokeh plot'
```

will pass